# Using Pods in Share Extension fails

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Inside my project I have a `shareExtension` and I need to install a `pod` for it.

I tried it like this:

```
target 'Wishlists' do

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Hero'
pod 'RevealingSplashView'
pod 'LBTAComponents'
pod 'lottie-ios'
pod 'SwiftEntryKit', '1.2.3'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'SkeletonView'
pod 'SwiftSoup'

end


target 'ShareExtension' do 

    pod 'SwiftSoup'

end
```

I simply tried adding the `target` and the `pod` I need (SwiftSoup), but my app is crushing now because the pods for my main project (Wishlists) do not work anymore. Does anyone know what's wrong with the file? Can not figure it out.. I ran `pod install` already.

Comment: what the crash says

Comment: @Sh_Khan I can not find module `FirebaseAuth` inside a `ViewController` in my main Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug.. I deleted `use frameworks!` by accident from my `podfile` inside the Main Project. I added it again and also had to add it to the `ShareExtension` and now it is working.